# how to retrieve uploaded url of zip files

Tags: php, uploads

following PHP code allow users to upload files frontend in wordpress
I've searched hours but I could not manage to display URLs of uploaded files.

I put in index.php

```
    <?php
if ( isset( $_POST['upload_attachments'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['secure_upload'], 'upload_attachments_nonce')) {

    //checking if upload is empty
    //checking if universal filesize is valid

    if ($_FILES) { //loop through multiple files.         
        $files = $_FILES['upload'];
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                $file = array(
                    'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
                );

                $uploaded_file_type = $files['type'][$key];
                $allowed_file_types = array('application/x-zip-compressed', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf', 'application/zip', 'video/mp4');
                $uploaded_file_size = $files['size'][$key];
                $size_in_kb = $uploaded_file_size / 1024;
                $file_size_limit = 10000; // Your Filesize in KB


                if(in_array($uploaded_file_type,  $allowed_file_types)) { 
                   if( $size_in_kb > $file_size_limit ) {
                   $upload_error .= 'Image files must be smaller than '.$file_size_limit.'KB';
                   return;
                   } else {
                   $_FILES = array("upload" => $file);
                   foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                   $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
                   //return; this loop neds to run multiple times so no return here
                 }      
                 }
                 } else { $upload_error .= 'Invalid File type';
                         return;
                        }                                                              

                }
            }
        }                  

    header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);//Post, redirect and get
    exit();
    }//end of nonce check ?>
```

and this is functions.php

```
    function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    //if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

additional question this code wont allow to upload rar file it uploads zip files only, is it possible to upload with it rar files too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To allow uploading files which are not in the 'regular' list of MIME's you have to tell WordPress to add them to that list.

As an **example** you find below code which adds those extensions to the already existing  MIMES list.

> *Please make a backup first*

```
/**
 * Source: @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/
 *
 */
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes' );
function add_custom_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes )
{
   return array_merge( $existing_mimes, array(
      'rar' => 'application/rar'
    ));

  return $existing_mimes;
}
```

It takes the existing array of allowed file types ($existing_mimes) first and adds the 'new' additionally to it.
The 'new' array will then be returned to WordPress.

I hope this will help you on your way when it is about allowing 'new' file.ext to upload.

**edit:**
*Simplified code, and perhaps the MIME type given for .rar extension (changed it into application, see code)* was wrong?!

Comment: I've pasted your code in my functions.php but I doesn't work in my case, and I'm getting following arror, which refers to line 37 of index.php
Notice: Undefined variable: upload_error in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress1\wp-content\themes\upload-zip\index.php on line 37

and the line 37 is:  `else { $upload_error .= 'Invalid File type';
                         return;
                        }`

Comment: Ehm, did you add `package/rar` to your allowed_file_types *(in your index.php)*? Because, imho has the error nothing to do with the code as given in the answer but with the code in the index php which says, that the file.type (rar in this case) is not on the allowed file type list and therefore calling your `$upload_error .= 'Invalid File type'`. *But I can be wrong of course*

Comment: Yes, I've added, I copied and pasted your code all the way down, but I'm getting same error, rar files wont upload, actually my basic question was how can I get URL back when mentioned files uploaded?

Comment: Does it give the same error without the above code from the answer?

Comment: Yes Charles I'm getting the same error I tested it with another theme but nothing changed, the error persists to occur. Do you know how to display back URL of newly uploaded files with this code, I need it to be showed to visitors when they upload a file. By the way I'm working on localhost with xampp server.